# Avoiding to loose the line breaks (\n) while reading and writing files

Tags: java, file-io, properties, line-breaks

i read several property files to compare them against a template file for missing keys.

```
FileInputStream compareFis = new FileInputStream(compareFile);
Properties compareProperties = new Properties();
compareProperties.load(compareFis);
```

Note: I read the template file the same way.

After reading i compare them and write the missing keys with their values from the template file into a Set.

```
CompareResult result = new CompareResult(Main.resultDir);
[...]
if (!compareProperties.containsKey(key)) {
    retVal = true;
    result.add(compareFile.getName(), key + "=" + entry.getValue());
}
```

At last i write the missing keys and their values into a new file.

```
for (Entry<String, SortedSet<String>> entry : resultSet) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new java.io.PrintWriter(resultFile);
        SortedSet<String> values = entry.getValue();
        for (String string : values) {
            out.println(string);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

If i open the result file i see that all line breaks "\n" from the values of the template file are replaced against a new line. Example:

```
test.key=Hello\nWorld!
```

becomes

```
test.key=Hello
World!
```

Although this is basically correct, but in my case I have to keep the "\n".

Does anyone know how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems that your output is a properties file, you should use [Properties.store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29) to generate the output file. This would not only take care of encoding the newline chars, but also the other special characters (non ISO8859-1 characters for example).

Answer (score 1):

Using `println` will end each line with the platform-specific line terminator. You can instead write the line terminator that you want explicitly:

```
for (Entry<String, SortedSet<String>> entry : resultSet) {
    PrintWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new java.io.PrintWriter(resultFile);
        SortedSet<String> values = entry.getValue();
        for (String string : values) {
            out.print(string); // NOT out.println(string)
            out.print("\n");
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add an example to JB Nizet answer (the best I think) using  [Properties.store()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
    FileInputStream compareFis = new FileInputStream(compareFile);
    Properties compareProperties = new Properties();
    compareProperties.load(compareFis);

 ....

    StringBuilder value=new StringBuilder();
    for (Entry<String, SortedSet<String>> entry : resultSet) {

            SortedSet<String> values = entry.getValue();
            for (String string : values) {
                value.append(string).append("\n");
            }
    }
    compareProperties.setProperty("test.key",value);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(compareFile);
    compareProperties.store(fos,null);
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
"test.key=Hello\\nWorld!"
```

where `"\\n"` is actually `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Escape the \n before serializing it. If you intend to read what you output file, your reading code will need to be aware of the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You might also look at the Apache Commons StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava( String ).